# Tricky problem with primary key in INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in a SQL Server database with autoincrementing primary key `[ID]`. Is there some way to include the `[ID]` column in the `INSERT` statement so that the database would ignore it? Some trick with table configuration?

I am not working on PC (on Omron NJ PLC), so I can't write statements myself. Instead they are mapped from Structs. And, if it is possible, I want to use same Structs for both `INSERT` and `SELECT` (where I need `[ID]` for a later `UPDATE`). Also I have no desire of generating index myself. Although it would be lesser evil.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you need to provide a value for columns that are inserted.  There is a special value called `DEFAULT` that inserts the default value.  However, it cannot be used with `IDENTITY` columns.

The normal `insert` method is to simply leave out the column:

```
insert into t (<all columns but id>)
    values (<all values for other columns>);
```

Even a trigger on the tables doesn't get around this limitation, but there is a trick you can use:

- Create a view on the table selecting all columns.
- Create an `instead of insert` trigger on the table.
- Insert into the *view* instead of the *table*.

This looks like:

```
create view v_t as
    select * from t;

create trigger trig_v on v_t instead of insert as
begin
    insert into t ( . . . )  -- all columns except id
        select . . .         -- all columns except id
        from inserted;
end;

insert into v_t -- I recommend listing the columns but not required
    values (NULL, . . . );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4ebc72a9971219a8e6f49136018e524) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you! Neat trick. Although I decided to take different approach, where this problem disappears, trigger came handy while solving another problem, I had.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert explicit value for the ID on an identity, you can use the SET INSERT_IDENTITY ON statement before your insert. After that you will enable again the identity by the statement SET INSERT_IDENTITY OFF.

Hope this helps.